# Setting date in html date input using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to set two dates into two different HTML date inputs. One for today and one for 30 days in the future. Here is my code:

```
function SetDate(date, dest){
    var dd = String(date.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
    var mm = String(date.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
    var yyyy = date.getFullYear();

    document.getElementById(dest).value = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
}
const date = new Date();
SetDate(date, 'sent');
SetDate(date.setDate(date.getDate() + 30), 'due');
```

This works for today's date and set's the correct date into the first HTML input, however, when it tries to set the second date 30 days in advance I get this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: date.getDate is not a function ... myscript.js:2
```

I just can't seem to figure out what the problem is.

Comment: Why 30 and not 31 or 28 or sometimes 29? ...just making sure 30 is for no reason 30...

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Because this calculates when an invoice was sent and when it is due which is always 30 days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `SetDate` expects a `Date` object as the first parameter. When you call

```js
SetDate(date.setDate(date.getDate() + 30), 'due');
```

you are passing a number, not a date, because `date.setDate(date.getDate() + 30)` will return a number. You can fix this by doing something like:

```js
let date = new Date();
SetDate(date, 'sent');
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 30);
SetDate(date, 'due');
```

Answer (score 0):

By  doing `date.setDate(date.getDate() + 30)` you'll get the number of MS.
You need to add days to a `new Date()` and return a `new Date()`

```js
const dateToISO8601 = (date) => `${date.getFullYear()}-${String(date.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2,'0')}-${String(date.getDate()).padStart(2,'0')}`;
const dateAddDays = (date, days) => new Date(new Date().setDate(date.getDate() + days));
const EL = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelector(sel);


const dateNow = new Date();
EL('#sent').value = dateToISO8601(dateNow);
EL('#due').value  = dateToISO8601(dateAddDays(dateNow, 30));
```

```html
<input id="sent">
<input id="due">
```